# add pagination to dynamic gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

**i have a dynamic gridview to which i can add a row dynamically....code for that is given below**

**.aspx page : (without pagination)**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Grid_AccEntry" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  GridLines="None"
 OnRowDeleting="Grid_AccEntry_RowDeleting" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">

 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

 <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="amount" runat="server" Width="100" Text='<%# Bind("amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>

     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Amount"
     ValidationGroup="Validation" ControlToValidate="amount" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DR/CR">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DrCr" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="D">Debit</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="C">Credit</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>             
         </ItemTemplate>              
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account">
         <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="account" runat="server" Width="100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="accountChanged"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="account" AutoPostBack="true"
            DataValueField="acc"  >
     </asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT  [Account] as [acc],[ADesc] as [account], [OpenItemC] as [opn] FROM [Account_M]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
         </ItemTemplate>              
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opr Unit">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="oprUnit" runat="server" Width="100" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="OUnitName" 
            DataValueField="OprUnit">
     </asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT  [OprUnit], SUBSTRING([OUnitName],0,50) as [OUnitName] FROM [OprUnit_M]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
         </ItemTemplate>              
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="dept" runat="server" Width="100"
            DataSourceID="deptSqlDataSource" DataTextField="DeptName" 
            DataValueField="DeptCode">
     </asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="deptSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT  [DeptCode], SUBSTRING([DeptName],0,50) as [DeptName] FROM [Department_M]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
         </ItemTemplate>              
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Affiliate">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="affiliate" runat="server" Width="100"
            DataSourceID="affilSqlDataSource" DataTextField="AfBUName" 
            DataValueField="AffilateBU">
     </asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="affilSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT  [AffilateBU], SUBSTRING([AfBUName],0,50) as [AfBUName] FROM [Affilate_M]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ItemTemplate>            
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Open Item">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="openItem" runat="server" Width="100"
            DataSourceID="openitmSqlDataSource" DataTextField="EmpName" 
            DataValueField="EmpCode">
     </asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="openitmSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT  [EmpCode], SUBSTRING([EmpName],0,50) as [EmpName] FROM [OpenItem_M]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ItemTemplate>            
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Line Narration">
         <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lineNar" Width="100"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>            
    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:CommandField DeleteText="Remove" ShowDeleteButton="True" />

    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#993300" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**.cs page :**

```
   private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("amount", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DrCr", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("account", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("oprUnit", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dept", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("affiliate", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("openItem", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("lineNar", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["amount"] = string.Empty;
        dr["DrCr"] = string.Empty;
        dr["account"] = string.Empty;
        dr["oprUnit"] = string.Empty;
        dr["dept"] = string.Empty;
        dr["affiliate"] = string.Empty;
        dr["openItem"] = string.Empty;
        dr["lineNar"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Grid_AccEntry.DataSource = dt;
        Grid_AccEntry.DataBind();
    }


    protected void addRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox amount = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("amount");
                    DropDownList DrCr = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DrCr");
                    DropDownList account = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("account");
                    DropDownList oprUnit = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("oprUnit");
                    DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("dept");
                    DropDownList affiliate = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("affiliate");
                    DropDownList openItem = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("openItem");
                    TextBox lineNar = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["amount"] = amount.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(amount.Text);
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["DrCr"] = DrCr.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["account"] = account.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["oprUnit"] = oprUnit.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["dept"] = dept.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["affiliate"] = affiliate.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["openItem"] = openItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["lineNar"] = lineNar.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Grid_AccEntry.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Grid_AccEntry.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }    

        SetPreviousData();
    }




    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox amount = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("amount");
                    DropDownList DrCr = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DrCr");
                    DropDownList account = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("account");
                    DropDownList oprUnit = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("oprUnit");
                    DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("dept");
                    DropDownList affiliate = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("affiliate");
                    DropDownList openItem = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("openItem");
                    TextBox lineNar = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");

                    amount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["amount"].ToString();
                    DrCr.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DrCr"].ToString();
                    account.Text = dt.Rows[i]["account"].ToString();
                    oprUnit.Text = dt.Rows[i]["oprUnit"].ToString();
                    dept.Text = dt.Rows[i]["dept"].ToString();
                    affiliate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["affiliate"].ToString();
                    openItem.Text = dt.Rows[i]["openItem"].ToString();
                    lineNar.Text = dt.Rows[i]["lineNar"].ToString();


                    //to bind long narr text to gridview line narr
                    TextBox lineNar1 = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");
                    if (lineNar1.Text == "")
                        lineNar1.Text = lngNar.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }




    private void SetRowData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox amount = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("amount");
                    DropDownList DrCr = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DrCr");
                    DropDownList account = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("account");
                    DropDownList oprUnit = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("oprUnit");
                    DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("dept");
                    DropDownList affiliate = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("affiliate");
                    DropDownList openItem = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("openItem");
                    TextBox lineNar = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["amount"] = amount.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(amount.Text);
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["DrCr"] = DrCr.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["account"] = account.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["oprUnit"] = oprUnit.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["dept"] = dept.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["affiliate"] = affiliate.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["openItem"] = openItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["lineNar"] = lineNar.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        //SetPreviousData();
    }




    protected void Grid_AccEntry_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        SetRowData();
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowIndex]);
                drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
                Grid_AccEntry.DataSource = dt;
                Grid_AccEntry.DataBind();

                SetPreviousData();
                amountChanged(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**here everything works fine...now for this gridview i want to add pagination.
i.e if i click on ADD button a new row should be added at the end of last page.
what changes i have to be do now to do tat???**